# CI on Visual Studio Online with external git repository

Tags: git, gitlab, azure-devops

I have private GitLab server where my Git repository is located. I set up build in VSO using new build system which is in Preview now. This build system supports external repositories but it is possible to run build continuously only if repository is either VSO's one from GitHub. There is no option to do it with other git repositories.
I can setup git hook on my GitLab that calls external url but I didn't find any info that VSO's build can be raised via API.
Can somebody propose any solution to this problem or workaround?

Comment: Clarify: where is located your GitLab ? Is it in your corporate network behind a firewall?

Comment: Right, it's in my corporate network with firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already designed the access and proper exposure of your infrastructure to VSO; in other words, that you run the build agent on-prem or that your private repositories are accessible from outside the corporate network.

VSO exposes REST API [Start a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/overview#CommontasksStartabuild), so should not be hard to queue a new build when needed.

Comment: Not sure it works for the new build system but rather for XAML-based one